# Setting the throughput with TC QDISC affects TCP but no UDP

Tags: ubuntu, tc

I am new to tc qdisc and I have been creating a script to change throughput, delay and losses. However, when I try to change the throughput levels I only see an effect on TCP traffic and not on the UDP one (when using iperf). I am not sure if it is a problem of configuration or a problem of understanding...

Python Script:

```
Mbps_init="5"
Ms_init="10"
Loss_init="10"


os.system("tc class add dev h2-eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate "+Mbps_init+"mbit")
os.system("tc qdisc add dev h2-eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay "+Ms_init+"ms loss "+Loss_init+"%")
os.system("tc filter add dev h2-eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.0.0.2/24 match ip dst 10.0.0.1/24 flowid 1:1")
```

TCP (I am not getting 5Mbps but we could consider it "close enough"):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  6] local 10.0.0.1 port 5001 connected with 10.0.0.2 port 38442
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  6]  0.0-11.1 sec  3.62 MBytes  2.75 Mbits/sec
```

UDP (I see the effect on packet losses but no on the bandwidth):

```
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 10.0.0.1 port 5001 connected with 10.0.0.2 port 59510
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]  0.0- 9.2 sec  1.14 MBytes  1.04 Mbits/sec  15.697 ms   78/  893 (8.7%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, if I am not mistaken, it is just that the UDP iperf sends 1Mb of data by default.

You can use the option -b in the iperf UDP mode to increase the amount of data sent. Then, you can start to see the limitation on the UDP traffic too.

Comment: As per `man iperf`: the default limit of 1 Mb/sec applies to both TCP and UDP: `-b --bandwidth n[kmgKMG] | npps` *set target bandwidth to n bits/sec (default 1 Mbit/sec) or n packets per sec.  This may be used with TCP or UDP.  For variable loads use format mean,standard deviation*